# Page numbers only on specific pages of a report

Tags: eclipse, birt

I know how to add page numbers to a report, but does anybody know how I can add page numbers *only* to specific pages of a report?

For example, I don't want the page number to appear on the cover page and the table of contents page and some other pages. Also, I want to start counting the page numbers at a specific page of the report (I want page 1 of the report to be the page after the table of contents for example).

Answer (score 1):

By adding this in master-page footer section you can add your page numers like
`<value-of> pageNumber </value-of>` in the value-of tag and it also gives the option to add your script in that section. Based on your logic it will display the page numbers.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Report may have different Master Pages on different pages. Create one Master Page with page numbering visible, one without. In the element starting new page select required Master Page in Property Editor -> Page Break -> Master Page.

For the second part it is not the real answer, but only my comment about. Changing way of page numbering was subject of many BIRT bugs and it may work only in some BIRT versions. It is the matter of affecting Master Page content by report content, while Master Pages are generated *before* report. See examples in Eclipse forum:

- [How to restart page numbering within a group in BIRT 3.7.1](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/840198/)
- [Page number and total page](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/273065/)

Answer (score 0):

PageNumber and Total page variable works in rptlibrary.

Add a library and drag and drop the grid which has pagenumber in the layout page where ever is required.